# How IText wrap automatically when decrease it's width in fabric js version 1.7.22?

Tags: fabricjs, scale, patch

I am using fabric js version 1.7.22. obviously it is too old but I can't change fabric js version due to project complexity.

I know that this is duplication of question but every question said that use **Textbox** object of fabric js for this functionality but I **can't use** that object. because in my project there are lot's of code and in complex structure and used at many place in code. so.

I am working in one text editor, in which , I use fabric js version 1.7.22. I used IText object of fabric js at every place where need to add text.

**current behavior** of fabric js `IText` is when we decrease `IText` width by scaling it. text will scale instead of wrap into new line like below GIF :

[image]

But I want Behavior like this (In **IText** Onject) ,Not in **Textbox** object and not in **Text** object. :

[image]

In short : when IText width is decrease, wrap text into new line in Itext object.
Is there any **patch** or override class for **Itext** which Provide this functionality. if yes then Please help me.

Comment: Why not **Testbox**? This is the only reason, why `Textbox` is there. *Textbox class, based on IText, allows the user to resize the text rectangle and wraps lines automatically.* And Textbox is subset of IText, it won't break any of your code

Comment: I can't use textbox, because in my code there are thousands of line and used at many place. as well as I need both kind of scaling. horizontal scaling and uni-scaling  also. horizontal scaling is provided by textbox but uni-scaling not. so.

Comment: Have you solved this situation? @mayurkukadiya

Comment: NO, I haven't found any solution yet. So I abort that feature for now. But you can find better approach in letest fabric js (Using Textbox Object)

Comment: As far as I understand this is the only difference between IText and Texbox? All sources pointed it this way. Do you think this is true?

Comment: Yes, I did also lot's of research about it, but I can't found any solution and all sourced are says only one thing i.e. use textbox.

Answer (score 1):

I use this in textbox tools hope it fix

> splitByGrapheme: true,